# How to add a colorbar properly in python 2.7.2?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am affraid this sounds like a noobish question, but I am in trouble coding a colorbar around my figures.

I took some time reading the documentation and these kind of examples : 
colorbar(mappable, cax=None, ax=None, use_gridspec=True, **kw)

and I can not understand what is required to make it work. Mostly I obtain this error : 
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'

Lets think about details later on. What is the easiet/more simple way to pop a colorbar along my fig which would auto scale I guess ( if it is the easiet way). Or maybe should I previously determine the min and max of my values ?

Thanks for your help !

Here is the code (Only the figure 1 matters to me) and I am aware it is poorly designed. The beginning is here to load data from previous files :

```
 from pylab import *
import matplotlib.animation as animation

from Tkinter import Tk 
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file

with load(filename) as data:
    XYslice = data['XYslice']
    XZslice = data['XZslice']
    target = data['target']
    Over = data['Over']
    wvl=data['wvl']
    NA = data['NA']
    Dt = data['t']
    dz = data['dz']

Ntime,N,Nplans=shape(XZslice)
dxy=wvl/(2.0*NA)/Over 

thebigone=max(XYslice[:,N/2,N/2])
XZslice[0,0,0]=thebigone
XYslice[0,0,0]=thebigone



fig=figure(1,figsize=(12,6))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
xlabel(r"$x (\mu m)$")
ylabel(r"$y (\mu m)$")
ax2=fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
xlabel(r"$x (\mu m)$")
ylabel(r"$z (\mu m)$")

I=zeros(shape(Dt))
dI=zeros(shape(Dt))

im1=ax1.imshow(XYslice[0,:,:],interpolation='none')#,extent=[-N*dxy/2.0,N*dxy/2.0,-N*dxy/2.0,N*dxy/2.0],cmap='hot')
im2=ax2.imshow(XZslice[0,:,:],interpolation='none')#,extent=[-N*dxy/2.0,N*dxy/2.0,-Nplans*dz/2.0,Nplans*dz/2.0],cmap='hot')

for ii in range(len(Dt)):
    zedata=float64(((XYslice[ii,:,:]**2)[where(target==1)]).reshape(-1))
    dI[ii]=(sqrt(var(zedata)))
    I[ii]=(mean(zedata))

figure(2)
subplot(121)
plot(Dt,array(I),'o',Dt,array(dI))
grid('on')
subplot(122)
#plot(Dt,array(dI)/array(I))
xlabel('Dt ($\mu m^ 2$)')

grid('on')

#
def init():
    im1.set_data(XYslice[0,:,:])

    im2.set_data(XZslice[0,:,:])
    return([im1,im2])

def animate(t):
    im1.set_data(XYslice[t,:,:])
    im2.set_data(XZslice[t,:,:])
    return [im1,im2]

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(len(Dt)),interval=250,
                              blit=True,init_func=init,repeat=True)

show()
```

Comment: No, let's not "think about the details later on". Please provide what code you have, ideally in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The answer depends on the details of your situation. There is no one answer that fits all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find out how to do it ... It was really easy. I had to add `colorbar(im2)` right after the definition of im2 ...

Have a good day !